# Is Putty needed if I am using the Windows Power Shell

Tags: powershell, ssh, putty

I am currently using Windows Powershell with Git I am mainly developing websites but I have noticed some developers like to use Putty Wanted to get some of your thoughts if its needed if I am using the PowerShell already since its a ssh.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are confusing the both. PowerShell is a shell environment for windows. Putty is a terminal emulator, mostly used for SSH and Telnet. Perhaps you are reffering to [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), which is a Linux "emulator" which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows.. Cygwin ships with Bash, but you can choose to use whatever shell or package using the installer.

Comment: I see ya its because I installed git to upload my code that I wrote with Django and I noticed it came with the Bash and the git shell but I also saw that other people are using Putty as well . For Now I have moved forward with the Git Shell for windows because it is so easy to use and simple but the putty I am not using but needed a good explanation as to what its for and if its necessary for a Developer thats just building websites

Comment: Ah yes, the git shell. Also if you need a good Git client i recommend http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Comment: thank you amofasser I appreciate it